# data grid view with sub columns on a particular column

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I am creating a form that generates reports. One of my columns (description), needs 2 sub columns (size and color)

It needs to look like this

[image]

From another stackoverflow post, I saw this link
[Build a Nested GridView Control with ASP.NET](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3633561/Build-a-Nested-GridView-Control-with-ASPNET.htm)

However, I do not want an entirely new data grid view in each row, each with their own header and what not. Specifically, I only need 1 column with 2 sub columns as exemplified in the imgur link. Perhaps I could hide headers for the sub data grid view for every row but the first? Seems like a dirty hack.

Anyone have any suggestions? Even if it is just a hack to make it look like what I need.

Comment: Based on your link, this is an ASP.NET question, correct?

Comment: Windows form application. Not ASP.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image (not loading), but why not use a ListView, which gives you full control over the UI, and can simplify this approach.  Nested GridView's can work, but can be messy because it controls the UI and you never know what it may render at runtime that can throw off your layout.  ListView works well because it's customized.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will take a look at that. Here is the image again http://imgur.com/lox4ZXB and mirror http://imageshack.us/a/img600/8296/uhdw.png